# React native project execution has been stopped

Tags: reactjs, react-native

React native is unable to compile / load the bundle because a package is not resolved. How do I get React native to compile the bundle?

[image]

Comment: Did you re-run your application after system restarts? if yes, there here is second question is this error while compiling or in browser?

Comment: Do the standard stuff to restart your app: `watchman watch-del-all, rm-rf node_modules, yarn cache clean, yarn install, yarn start`

Comment: @vijayst am tried this method .Still same issue raised

Comment: @HemadriDasari yes , am re-run application.This is issues raised after compiling

Comment: What command you used to run your application?

Comment: react-native run-ios for IOS and react-native run-android for Android

Comment: Sorry can’t help you I don’t have knowledge on android or IOS.

Comment: @HemadriDasari ,its ok. Thank you for your response

Comment: Are u using typescript? Why is it referring to typescript node_modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got solution,

```
/Users/mac/Library/Caches/typescript/2.6/nodw_modules/@type/prop-types
```

line somehow imported automatically DashboardScreen.js . Am just removed that line and restart my package manager then it works for me.